# call a javascript function returned inside an xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, xmlhttprequest

I have multiple forms dynamically being created via an xmlhttp request to a php script.
everything works except each returned chunk (form in my case) has a javascript as part of the returned packet to validate the form. There are MANY forms, all with different validations, and not all are loaded, only ones needed based on previous form response. How do I call the function?

The form is put inside a . I keep getting object or function undefined when I call the function.

It is impractical to load ALL the validation scripts at once not to mention the file bloat it causes.
I prefer not using jquery or other libraries as they have many functions not needed wich also adds to the bloat.

thnks!
Gary

Comment: can you add some sample code or create a pseudo-example via jsfiddle?  It's not very clear what you are trying to accomplish without example code.

Comment: Does each downloaded "form chunk" get validated by the same *named* function, or is each form's function different?